# Spring authorization server (Spring security) not working with ADFS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, saml, cas, adfs

I am trying to implement support for ADFS in Spring authorization server which is using Spring security. I am able to connect with Github for authentication and am able to generate token after authentication using Github but while I am extending my application to support authentication via ADFS it's throwing an error that it is unable to download metadata.

[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwLUY.jpg) depicting my current project structure, and I have followed a sample application from Github [Saml with spring security](https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample)

**Logs**

```
**2018-02-09 15:06:48.755 ERROR 5332 --- [Metadata-reload] o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider       : Metadata provider failed to properly initialize, fail-fast=true, halting
org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Error retrieving metadata from https://caeladserver.cloudapp.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:267) ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.doInitialization(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:236) ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractMetadataProvider.initialize(AbstractMetadataProvider.java:407) ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate.initialize(ExtendedMetadataDelegate.java:167) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.initializeProvider(MetadataManager.java:412) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.refreshMetadata(MetadataManager.java:238) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager.refreshMetadata(CachingMetadataManager.java:86) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager$RefreshTask.run(MetadataManager.java:1040) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_121]**
```

**Code for my authorization server** and spring boot services as follows

```
public class CoreCasApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CoreCasApplication.class, args);
}

public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("login");
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    registry.addViewController("/homepage").setViewName("homepage");
    registry.addViewController("/logout").setViewName("logout");
}

@RequestMapping("/user")
public Principal user(Principal user) {
    return user;
}

@Configuration
@Order(-20)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
protected static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off

        final CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter customBasicAuthFilter = new CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter(
                this.authenticationManager());

        // @formatter:on
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER).invalidSessionUrl("/login")
                .sessionAuthenticationErrorUrl("/login").and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage", false).failureUrl("/login?error=true").and().requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/logout", "/homepage", "/login?error=true", "/oauth/authorize",
                        "/oauth/confirm_access", "/login/github","/saml/**")
                .and().logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true).permitAll().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login**", "/", "/login**", "/webjars/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/")).and()
                .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class).addFilterAfter(samlFilter(),BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        ;

        //http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint());
        http.csrf().disable();

    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(filter);
        registration.setOrder(-100);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("github")
    public ClientResources github() {
        return new ClientResources();
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
        List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        filters.add(ssoFilter(github(), "/login/github"));
        filter.setFilters(filters);
        return filter;
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
                path);
        OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
        oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);
        UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(),
                client.getClient().getClientId());
        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);
        oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
        return oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        auth.authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private Timer backgroundTaskTimer;
    private MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.backgroundTaskTimer = new Timer(true);
        this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        this.backgroundTaskTimer.purge();
        this.backgroundTaskTimer.cancel();
        this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.shutdown();
    }

    private SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl samlUserDetailsServiceImpl;

    // Initialization of the velocity engine
    @Bean
    public VelocityEngine velocityEngine() {
        return VelocityFactory.getEngine();
    }

    // XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing
    @Bean(initMethod = "initialize")
    public StaticBasicParserPool parserPool() {
        return new StaticBasicParserPool();
    }

    @Bean(name = "parserPoolHolder")
    public ParserPoolHolder parserPoolHolder() {
        return new ParserPoolHolder();
    }

    // Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing
    // messages
    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient() {
        return new HttpClient(this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager);
    }

    // SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received
    // SAML
    // messages
    @Bean
    public SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider() {
        SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider = new SAMLAuthenticationProvider();
        samlAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetails(samlUserDetailsServiceImpl);
        samlAuthenticationProvider.setForcePrincipalAsString(false);
        return samlAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    // Provider of default SAML Context
    @Bean
    public SAMLContextProviderImpl contextProvider() {
        return new SAMLContextProviderImpl();
    }

    // Initialization of OpenSAML library
    @Bean
    public static SAMLBootstrap sAMLBootstrap() {
        return new SAMLBootstrap();
    }

    // Logger for SAML messages and events
    @Bean
    public SAMLDefaultLogger samlLogger() {
        return new SAMLDefaultLogger();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileConsumer webSSOprofileConsumer() {
        return new WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOprofileConsumer() {
        return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfile webSSOprofile() {
        return new WebSSOProfileImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOProfile() {
        return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 ECP profile
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileECPImpl ecpprofile() {
        return new WebSSOProfileECPImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public SingleLogoutProfile logoutprofile() {
        return new SingleLogoutProfileImpl();
    }

    // Central storage of cryptographic keys
    @Bean
    public KeyManager keyManager() {
        DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
        Resource storeFile = loader.getResource("classpath:saml/caelcert.jks");
        String storePass = "Jan@2018";
        Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<String, String>();
        passwords.put("corekey", "Jan@2018");
        String defaultKey = "corekey";
        return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, storePass, passwords, defaultKey);
    }

    // Setup TLS Socket Factory
    @Bean
    public TLSProtocolConfigurer tlsProtocolConfigurer() {
        return new TLSProtocolConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public ProtocolSocketFactory socketFactory() {
        return new TLSProtocolSocketFactory(keyManager(), null, "allowAll");
    }

    @Bean
    public Protocol socketFactoryProtocol() {
        return new Protocol("https", socketFactory(), 443);
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodInvokingFactoryBean socketFactoryInitialization() {
        MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetClass(Protocol.class);
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetMethod("registerProtocol");
        Object[] args = { "https", socketFactoryProtocol() };
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(args);
        return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileOptions defaultWebSSOProfileOptions() {
        WebSSOProfileOptions webSSOProfileOptions = new WebSSOProfileOptions();
        webSSOProfileOptions.setIncludeScoping(false);
        return webSSOProfileOptions;
    }

    // Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from
    // properties file
    @Bean
    public SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint() {
        SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint = new SAMLEntryPoint();
        samlEntryPoint.setDefaultProfileOptions(defaultWebSSOProfileOptions());
        return samlEntryPoint;
    }

    // Setup advanced info about metadata
    @Bean
    public ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata() {
        ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = new ExtendedMetadata();
        extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryEnabled(true);
        extendedMetadata.setSignMetadata(false);
        extendedMetadata.setEcpEnabled(true);
        return extendedMetadata;
    }

    // IDP Discovery Service
    @Bean
    public SAMLDiscovery samlIDPDiscovery() {
        SAMLDiscovery idpDiscovery = new SAMLDiscovery();
        idpDiscovery.setIdpSelectionPath("/saml/idpSelection");
        return idpDiscovery;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("idp-corekey")
    public ExtendedMetadataDelegate ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider() throws MetadataProviderException {
        String idpSSOCircleMetadataURL = "https://caeladserver.cloudapp.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml";
        HTTPMetadataProvider httpMetadataProvider = new HTTPMetadataProvider(this.backgroundTaskTimer, httpClient(),
                idpSSOCircleMetadataURL);
        httpMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());
        ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate = new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(httpMetadataProvider,
                extendedMetadata());
        extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(false);
        extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
        backgroundTaskTimer.purge();
        return extendedMetadataDelegate;
    }

    // IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of
    // trust
    // is here
    // Do no forget to call iniitalize method on providers
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("metadata")
    public CachingMetadataManager metadata() throws MetadataProviderException {
        List<MetadataProvider> providers = new ArrayList<MetadataProvider>();
        providers.add(ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider());
        return new CachingMetadataManager(providers);
    }

    // Filter automatically generates default SP metadata
    @Bean
    public MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator() {
        MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator = new MetadataGenerator();
        metadataGenerator.setEntityId("http://caeladserver.cloudapp.net/adfs/services/trust");
        metadataGenerator.setExtendedMetadata(extendedMetadata());
        metadataGenerator.setIncludeDiscoveryExtension(false);
        metadataGenerator.setKeyManager(keyManager());
        return metadataGenerator;
    }

    // The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with
    // filterSuffix
    // and presents SP metadata there
    @Bean
    public MetadataDisplayFilter metadataDisplayFilter() {
        return new MetadataDisplayFilter();
    }

    // Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login
    @Bean
    public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
        return successRedirectHandler;
    }

    // Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login
    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
        failureHandler.setUseForward(true);
        failureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/error");
        return failureHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter = new SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter();
        samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
        samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        return samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter;
    }

    // Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages
    @Bean
    public SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter = new SAMLProcessingFilter();
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        return samlWebSSOProcessingFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MetadataGeneratorFilter metadataGeneratorFilter() {
        return new MetadataGeneratorFilter(metadataGenerator());
    }

    // Handler for successful logout
    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler() {
        SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler = new SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler();
        successLogoutHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
        return successLogoutHandler;
    }

    // Logout handler terminating local session
    @Bean
    public SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler() {
        SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
        logoutHandler.setInvalidateHttpSession(true);
        logoutHandler.setClearAuthentication(true);
        return logoutHandler;
    }

    // Filter processing incoming logout messages
    // First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after
    // successful
    // global logout
    @Bean
    public SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter samlLogoutProcessingFilter() {
        return new SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter(successLogoutHandler(), logoutHandler());
    }

    // Overrides default logout processing filter with the one processing
    // SAML
    // messages
    @Bean
    public SAMLLogoutFilter samlLogoutFilter() {
        return new SAMLLogoutFilter(successLogoutHandler(), new LogoutHandler[] { logoutHandler() },
                new LogoutHandler[] { logoutHandler() });
    }

    // Bindings
    private ArtifactResolutionProfile artifactResolutionProfile() {
        final ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl artifactResolutionProfile = new ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl(
                httpClient());
        artifactResolutionProfile.setProcessor(new SAMLProcessorImpl(soapBinding()));
        return artifactResolutionProfile;
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPArtifactBinding artifactBinding(ParserPool parserPool, VelocityEngine velocityEngine) {
        return new HTTPArtifactBinding(parserPool, velocityEngine, artifactResolutionProfile());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPSOAP11Binding soapBinding() {
        return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPPostBinding httpPostBinding() {
        return new HTTPPostBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding httpRedirectDeflateBinding() {
        return new HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPSOAP11Binding httpSOAP11Binding() {
        return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPPAOS11Binding httpPAOS11Binding() {
        return new HTTPPAOS11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    // Processor
    @Bean
    public SAMLProcessorImpl processor() {
        Collection<SAMLBinding> bindings = new ArrayList<SAMLBinding>();
        bindings.add(httpRedirectDeflateBinding());
        bindings.add(httpPostBinding());
        bindings.add(artifactBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine()));
        bindings.add(httpSOAP11Binding());
        bindings.add(httpPAOS11Binding());
        return new SAMLProcessorImpl(bindings);
    }

    /**
     * Define the security filter chain in order to support SSO Auth by
     * using SAML 2.0
     * 
     * @return Filter chain proxy
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Bean
    public FilterChainProxy samlFilter() throws Exception {
        List<SecurityFilterChain> chains = new ArrayList<SecurityFilterChain>();
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/login/**"), samlEntryPoint()));
        chains.add(
                new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/logout/**"), samlLogoutFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/metadata/**"),
                metadataDisplayFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSO/**"),
                samlWebSSOProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSOHoK/**"),
                samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SingleLogout/**"),
                samlLogoutProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/discovery/**"),
                samlIDPDiscovery()));
        return new FilterChainProxy(chains);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the authentication manager currently used by Spring. It
     * represents a bean definition with the aim allow wiring from other
     * classes performing the Inversion of Control (IoC).
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager auth;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    @Bean
    public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
        return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices()).authenticationManager(auth)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore()).approvalStoreDisabled().tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }
}

@Autowired
public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}

}
```

**Class for Client Resources**

```
class ClientResources {
@NestedConfigurationProperty
private AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails client = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

@NestedConfigurationProperty
private ResourceServerProperties resource = new ResourceServerProperties();

public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails getClient() {
    return client;
}

public ResourceServerProperties getResource() {
    return resource;
}
}
```

**Class to implement SAMLUserDetailsService**

```
@Service
public class SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl implements SAMLUserDetailsService {

// Logger
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl.class);

public Object loadUserBySAML(SAMLCredential credential)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    // The method is supposed to identify local account of user referenced by
    // data in the SAML assertion and return UserDetails object describing the user.

    String userID = credential.getNameID().getValue();

    LOG.info(userID + " is logged in");
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
    authorities.add(authority);

    // In a real scenario, this implementation has to locate user in a arbitrary
    // dataStore based on information present in the SAMLCredential and
    // returns such a date in a form of application specific UserDetails object.
    return new User(userID, "<abc123>", true, true, true, true, authorities);
}

}
```

**Class to implement HandlerMethodArgumentResolver**

```
@Component
public class CurrentUserHandlerMethodArgumentResolver implements
        HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
    return methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(CurrentUser.class) != null
            && methodParameter.getParameterType().equals(User.class);
}

public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter,
        ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
        WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
    if (this.supportsParameter(methodParameter)) {
        Principal principal = (Principal) webRequest.getUserPrincipal();
        return (User) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal();
    } else {
        return WebArgumentResolver.UNRESOLVED;
    }
}
}
```

**Commands used for certificate importion to key store**

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass Jan@2018 -alias corekey -keypass Jan@2018 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

keytool -genkeypair  -keystore "PathToJKS"  -storepass Jan@2018  -alias corekey -keyalg RSA

keytool -list -v -alias corekey  -keystore "PathToJKS"  -storepass Jan@2018 -keypass Jan@2018

keytool -delete -alias corekey  -keystore "PathToJKS" -storepass Jan@2018

keytool -import -alias corekey  -file adfscert.cer -keystore "PathToJKS" -storepass Jan@2018 –noprompt
```

Comment: please fix your formatting and spelling

Comment: the error "Error retrieving metadata" applies to the browser as well. The URL cannot be opened due to SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER (self signed cert). Does your metadata parser need to import the certificate?

Comment: Yes It needs to  import the certificate