# Securing Spring Boot API with oAuth2 | filter users

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a Spring boot API that I managed to secure with oAuth2 and Google. 
I have something similar to this: [Rest, Spring own OAuth2 server + OAuth2 providers like Facebook, Google, Yahoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547671/rest-spring-own-oauth2-server-oauth2-providers-like-facebook-google-yahoo?newreg=21be6cb40f4c40e6abf8318468f4671d)

Everything works as expected.

My question is the following:
How can I know limit the access to certain users (not every google user) ?
This sounds like the authorization part to me. I'm not sure where to start as I'm a beginner in all this.

Thanks for any help or pointer.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to limit the access to everyone except google users?

Comment: Not Really. Now I have every google user able to access/use the API. What I want is to limit the access to certain google users based on something from their profile (let's say their last name for example)

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, if you want to limit access to an API based on a user's last name (going by your example) I will set up a sample scenario of something I might do.

Say for instance I have an API with an endpoint such as `/api/family?lastname=doe` and the purpose of this API is to return a list of people with the same last name as "doe" in this case.  The API will only return a result if the last name provided in the parameter is equal to the current authorized user's last name.

So maybe I'd have an API set up as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/family", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Member> findFamilyMembersByLastName(@RequestParam(value="lastname", required=true) String lastName){

      User authorizedUser = getCurrentUser(); // Set up a method that is able to get the current logged in user
      if(!authorizedUser.getLastName().equals(lastName){
         // Throw some kind of exception here
      }
      // otherwise perform a query to find a list of Members with last name and return them

}
```